# Php Excel encoding issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

I am converting exporting some database values to excel using phpexcel. When i echo the value everything works fine but when i am trying to export the value to excel for example `The Westminster Terrace,Yau Lai Rd&#13;&#10; Hong Kong` it just print the same in excel whereas if i echo it prints `The Westminster Terrace, Yau Lai Rd , Hong Kong`.
The database has utf8_general_ci collation. I had used the following code .

```
foreach ($data as $question) {
    $c = $c + 1;
    //echo $question['their_answer'];
    $objPHPExcel -> setActiveSheetIndex(0) -> setCellValue($x . $d, $question['their_answer']);
$x++;
}
```

How to print the same in excel column as echoed any idea?
Thanks
Somdeb

Comment: The `&#13;` and `&#10;` are entities, I think control characters. When you say `When i echo the value everything works fine` are you in a browser? If so the browser is rendering those. Take a look at the source and it will be the same.

Comment: yes in browser but the output is different in excel

Comment: @SomdebMukherjee Because the browser can interpret HTML, and these are HTML Entities. Excel cannot.

Comment: Yea, browsers render entities as their characters. You have two answers below take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These characters are HTML entities. Try [**html_entity_decode**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), like this:

```
foreach ($data as $question) {
    $c = $c + 1;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($x . $d, html_entity_decode($question['their_answer']));
    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because Excel isn't HTML and `&#13;` and `&#10;` are HTML Entities (actually encoded carriage return and line feed characters)..... they're nothing more than literal character in a string to Excel. You need to convert them to their UTF-8 character using something like [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$string = 'The Westminster Terrace,Yau Lai Rd&#13;&#10; Hong Kong';
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

You'll probably also want to set the cell to wrap, and autoheight for the row to handle those return characters as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're experiencing problems with the entities eg: `&#13;`.

Try to decode the entities using `html_entity_decode` while running your code like this:

```
foreach ($data as $question) {
    $c = $c + 1;
    //echo $question['their_answer'];
    $objPHPExcel -> setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($x . $d, html_entity_decode($question['their_answer']));
$x++;
}
```

The reason for this, may be the fact that your database already saved data with the entities encoded, so it will print correctly in the browser when you `echo` but won't print in the excel file (because he can't understand what those values are)

Let me know if it works.